# Did the men of Solomon's time preferred lighter skin women?

Tags: hebrew, authorial-intent, symbolism, song-of-songs

Song of Solomon 1:5 I am dark, yet lovely, O daughters of Jerusalem,
like the tents of Kedar, like the curtains of Solomon.
6 Do not stare because I am dark,
for the sun has gazed upon me.
My mother’s sons were angry with me;
they made me a keeper of the vineyards,
but my own vineyard I have neglected.

Comment: Royalty and nobility, unlike peasants, do not spend their days toiling the field, exposed to the heat of the sun.

Comment: A Shechorah Shepherdess physically demonstrates more love for God's flocks by enduring the burning sun, while other maidens stay veiled (under tents) to find comfort from Godly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Song of Solomon 1:6 Do not stare because I am dark

This shows the sentiment of the woman herself. It does not necessarily reflect the preference of the men. On the other hand, we have Song of Solomon 1:8

> If you do not know, **most beautiful of women**, follow the tracks of the sheep and graze your young goats by the tents of the shepherds.

This one shows the general perception. Even though she is dark, they think she is most beautiful.

This is true today. An individual woman has her own sense of what is lacking in her beauty while others may not agree.

Answer (score 4):

In context to the poem, we find in Song of Songs ( שִׁ֥יר הַשִּׁירִ֖ים ) Chapter 1 : verse 5 - **The Woman who loves My-Beloved (Dodi, דּוֹדִ֥י)** is questioning the contributions of Maidens who supposedly love God by examining their physical lack of hard labor for His city Yerushalem.

Song of Songs ( שִׁ֥יר הַשִּׁירִ֖ים ) - Chapter 1:7 [MT]

> "Tell me, you whom my soul loves, where do you feed, where do you rest [the flocks] at noon, for **why should I be like one who veils herself beside the flocks of your companions**?" (הַגִּ֣ידָה לִּ֗י שֶׁ֤אָֽהֲבָה֙ נַפְשִׁ֔י אֵיכָ֣ה תִרְעֶ֔ה אֵיכָ֖ה תַּרְבִּ֣יץ בַּֽצָּֽהֳרָ֑יִם שַׁלָּמָ֤ה אֶֽהְיֶה֙ כְּעֹ֣טְיָ֔ה עַ֖ל עֶדְרֵ֥י חֲבֵרֶֽיךָ )

**The Woman who loves My-Beloved (דּוֹדִ֥י) does not cover her face in the heat of the day, so the sun burns her while she contributes her services to help feed God's sheep.**

The physical attribute of the Woman who loves Dodi (דּוֹדִ֥י) being **"Black" (Shechorah, שְׁחוֹרָ֤ה)** in Chapter 1, verse 5 is explained in verse 7 through the hard labor of a **devoted shepherdess** caring more about God's sheep than her own comfort under the burning sun.

Song of Songs (שִׁ֥יר הַשִּׁירִ֖ים) - Chapter 1:5 [MT]

> "**Black** I am but-comely, O daughters of Yerushalem! Like the tents of Kedar, like the curtains of **Shlomoh**." (שְׁחוֹרָ֤ה אֲנִי֙ וְֽנָאוָ֔ה בְּנ֖וֹת יְרֽוּשָׁלָ֑יִם כְּאָֽהֳלֵ֣י קֵדָ֔ר כִּֽירִיע֖וֹת שְׁלֹמֹֽה  )

A **Shechorah (שְׁחוֹרָ֤ה)** Shepherdess physically demonstrates more love for God's flocks by enduring the burning sun, while other maidens stay veiled (under tents) to find comfort from Godly work.